# How to export a dictionary in LIWC dictionary format using R quanteda

Tags: r, dictionary, quanteda

In quanteda one can import LIWC format dictionaries. But is there a way to export a dictionary from quanteda to LIWC format?

a sample of dictionary format for LIWC is below (the part between the % is the name of each category):

```
%
462 Asentir
463 NoFluen
464 Relleno
%
a   1   17
abad    259
abadía  259
abajo   1   17  250 252
abandon*    137
abandona    11  14  125 127 130 131 255
abandonáis  11  14  125 127 130 131 255
abandonamos 11  13  14  125 127 130 131 255
abandonan   11  14  125 127 130 131 255
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to export a **quanteda** dictionary as a LIWC formatted dictionary (file), but you could file this as an issue on the source (GitHub) repository as a feature request.

In the [**quanteda.dictionaries** package](https://github.com/kbenoit/quanteda.dictionaries), there is a function `liwcalike()` that inputs a LIWC-formatted dictionary and produces a data.frame identical in content and format to the output produced by the stand-alone LIWC software (and this is easy to save as a spreadsheet file if you need it that way). So if you are asking because you feel you need to use the LIWC software to produce a dictionary analysis, `liwcalike()` might provide a ready replacement.